# Need a hand understanding reading CSV files and using them in java

Tags: java, csv

I'm trying to read a CSV file which contains GPS coordinates (latitude, longitude and elevation) as well as time stamps for each instance. The format is as follows:

2014-08-06T21:02:23Z, -33.7939310, 151.0553090, -5.0

With this separate each into a way-point (basically placing each row into an array) and then picking apart each way-point to get each data member as its own string. So just a quick overview of what i've done so far.

I've separated the string by a comma to give 4 separate strings and then used `parseDouble` to change the numerical strings into doubles.

I think that my formatting is wrong but I'm not 100% sure as I'm still quite new to java the last method will involve using the data from the "getters".

I'm struggling to get a grasp on this project!

```
public class Waypoint {

// The radius of the Earth in km
final double R = 6373.0; 

public double getLatitude(String[] field) {
    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(field[3]);

    
    
    return latitude; 
}

public double getLongitude(String[] field) {
    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(field[2]);

    return longitude;

}

public double getElevation(String[] field) {
    double elevation = Double.parseDouble(field[4]);
    
    
    return elevation;
}

public String getTimestamp(String[] field) {
    String date = field[1];
    
    
    return date;
}

public Waypoint(final String wstring) throws GPSException, FileNotFoundException  {
    
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(wstring));

    scanner.hasNextLine();

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String waypoint = scanner.nextLine();           
        String[] field = waypoint.split(",");           
    }
    
}

public double distanceTo(Waypoint wp2) {
    
    
    
    
}

}
```

Comment: What makes you think that there is something wrong?

Comment: I just don't see how i'm going to be able to calculate the distance between each way-point because of the way I've written my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't worded correctly, and that will get you bashed every time out here.

The first thing you need to do is read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Given that, you need to post your problem being encountered, which I assume is an ArrayOutOfBoundsException since java arrays start at index 0, not 1.

After that I imagine that you are having issues with Dates, which are complicated, because you should be using a Date parser instead of what you have stated above.

I am also assuming you know how to calculate the distance between two coordinates, if not that is a separate question.

You need to start breaking things down into something more object oriented.

Most school assignments don't want you using libraries like OpenCsv, hence your scanner. You can take your scanner, assuming it is working for you and just create a structure to pass to a factory. I would Suggest `List<String[]>`, each String array being a row in the CSV file.

You should think in terms of classes, for instance a coordinate class as follows:

```
package com.techtrip.labs.stackoverflow;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

public class Coordinate {

    private ZonedDateTime timeStamp;
    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
    private Double elevation;

    public Coordinate() {
        super();
    }

    public ZonedDateTime getTimeStamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    public void setTimeStamp(ZonedDateTime timeStamp) {
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    public Double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public Double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Double getElevation() {
        return elevation;
    }

    public void setElevation(Double elevation) {
        this.elevation = elevation;
    }
}
```

And use a helper class (or perhaps an interface with default methods in Java 8)

```
package com.techtrip.labs.stackoverflow;

import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class CoordinateFactory {

    public List<Coordinate> getCoordinates(List<String[]> raw) {
        List<Coordinate> coordinates = new ArrayList<Coordinate>(raw.size());

        for (String[] row : raw) {
            coordinates.add(createCoordinate(row));
        }

        return coordinates;

    }

    private Coordinate createCoordinate(String... args) {
        // add error checking here as an assignment
        Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate();

        coordinate.setTimeStamp(parseToLocalDateTime(args[0]));
        coordinate.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(args[1]));
        coordinate.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(args[2]));
        coordinate.setElevation(Double.parseDouble(args[3]));
        return coordinate;
    }

    private ZonedDateTime parseToLocalDateTime(String timeStamp) {
        // SEE Java 8 API Documentation on how to
        // Parse your date into a proper date time format

        /*
         * Let as assignment for ops
         * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java
         * /time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html
         * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html
         */

        return null;
    }
}
```

Finally write a method to calculate the distance between two coordinates, I am making the final assumption that you have the algorithm handy. You can put the following in your main.

```
public static Double distanceBetween(Coordinate c1, Coordinate c2){

    // This should be your starting point
    return null; // replace null with the value
}
```

All of this should handle a good part of your structural stuff. A complete program should have error checking, for instance to make sure that each row has 4 properly formatted values.

Test each method one at a time any way you can. It will help you understand what is going on.